# C# regex replace with file content

Tags: c#, regex

The input is something like `include("blablabal.bla")` and i want to replace it with content from file blablabal.bla. Is it possible in C#?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's possible. =)
Do you need it in a console, winforms or a server side app?

Comment: Well, you already have something similar in server side applications. But what did you tried so far?

Comment: Could someone explain me why this question got that bad score? I think it's normal question and it has useful answer - thanks Rubens Farias! :)

Comment: Your question doesn't have any code. Also the closing reason states: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look into the `Regex.Replace` method. There is a version which receives a match delegate and can be used like this:

```
var include = new Regex(@"include\(""(?<filename>.*?)""\)");
var input   = File.ReadAllText("c:\\sample.txt");
var output  = include.Replace(input, (match) =>
{
    if (match.Success)
    {
        var filename = match.Groups["filename"].Value;
        // TODO: make this secure. Imagine this: include("c:\passwords.txt")
        if (File.Exists(filename))
            return File.ReadAllText(filename);
    }
    return "Invalid directive: " + match.Value;
});
```